# Constructing a long Python string using variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting, f-string

I have a python string which is basically a concatenation of 3 variables.I am using `f-strings` to make it a string. It looks like this now:

```
my_string = f'{getattr(RequestMethodVerbMapping, self.request_method).value} {self.serializer.Meta.model.__name__} {self.request_data['name']}'
```

which gives me the output:

```
Create IPGroup test-create-demo-098
```

Exactly the output that I want. However, as is obvious the line is too long and now Pylint starts complaining so I try to break up the line using multiline `f-strings` as follows:

```
my_string = f'''{getattr(RequestMethodVerbMapping, self.request_method).value} 
                {self.serializer.Meta.model.__name__} {self.request_data['name']}'''
```

Pylint is now happy but my string looks like this:

```
Create 
                  IPGroup test-create-demo-098
```

What is the best way of doing this so that I get my string in one line and also silence Pylint for the line being longer than 120 chars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to concat f-strings with just whitespace in between, just like ordinary strings. Just parenthesize the whole thing.

```
my_string = (f'{getattr(RequestMethodVerbMapping, self.request_method).value}' 
             f' {self.serializer.Meta.model.__name__}
             f' {self.request_data["name"]}')
```

It will compile to exactly the same code as your one-line string.

It is even possible to interleave f-strings and non-f-strings:

```
>>> print(f"'foo'" '"{bar}"' f'{1 + 42}')
'foo'"{bar}"43
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a long line by itself and, instead of trying to fit a lot into a single line, I would break it down and apply the ["Extract Variable"](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html) refactoring method for readability:

```
request_method_name = getattr(RequestMethodVerbMapping, self.request_method).value
model_name = self.serializer.Meta.model.__name__
name = self.request_data['name']

my_string = f'{request_method_name} {model_name} {name}'
```

I think the following pieces of wisdom from the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) fit our problem here well:

> Sparse is better than dense.
>
> Readability counts.